# File Tranfer with XMPP (openfire) and Flex

Tags: file, flex3, xmpp, openfire

I have a chat application that connects to google,msn, AOL and yahoo through XMPP server. i am able to send the text messages . now i would like to implement the file Tranfer between the entities? how to proceed with it... plz help me with links and if possible source code.
thanks and regards,
-rushi

Answer (score 0):

Check Jingle xmpp especification:

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0234.html

Bye